# Как запустить инсталятор внутри формы?

Tags: c#, exe

Язык C#
Как запустить exe инсталятор программы внутри формы своей программы?
Это на тот случай если инсталятор не поддерживает тихий режим установки. То как вариант,  можно запустить инсталятор в своей форме, а форму потом скрыть.

Comment: зачем запихивать внутрь формы? Если нужно скрыть окно, просто ShowWindow(hWnd,SW_HIDE);

Comment: Во внутрь я так понимаю не запихнуть? Инсталятор не скрывается таким способом как вы показали. А ещё по инсталятору нужно нажать будет.

Comment: То есть вы хотите скрыть от юзера факт инсталляции?

Comment: Как ни странно, запихнуть можно. Функция SetParent, она (обычно) работает для окон из другого процесса, попробуйте сами. Главное не забыть разорвать отношения между окнами до завершения одного из процессов, иначе второй упадет.

Comment: Дорогой MSDN.WhiteKnight, а вы не хотите за деньгу написать программку с небольшим набором функций?

Comment: SetParent не работает.. (